# The type number of an algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, noncommutative-algebra, central-simple-algebras

I've been reading *[On the existence of maximal orders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2897)*, by C.F. Yu, in which he discusses maximal $R$-orders in semisimple algebras over a field $K$, where $R$ is a Noetherian integral domain and $K = \operatorname{frac}(R)$. He specialises to the case of a central simple algebra $A$ over a number field $K$, with $R=\mathcal{O}_K$, and mentions (page 15, section 5.2) that 'the set of conjugacy classes of maximal $R$-orders may not be singleton; its cardinality, if is finite, is called the *type number* of $A$.'

My question is: what do we know about type numbers? Does Jordan-Zassenhaus imply finiteness of the type number in this case? Any references on type numbers of central simple algebras would be greatly appreciated.